# Adding a local user from one Windows machine to a local group on another Windows machine

Tags: user-management, windows, remote-access, windows-server-core

I would like to add a local user account from a remote computer to a local group on a Windows "server core" box. Neither the workstation, nor the server are in a domain. Is that possible?

Will something like this work? `net localgroup "Distributed COM Users" /add computer\user`

Comment: Just a note: this is for remote administration. I need to manage the server from a box on the same network, so I'm looking for a way to get the server to recognize the user's credentials.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No, it's not possible. You can't add a local user from `MachineA` to a local group on `MachineB`.

If you create a local user on the server that is the same as the local user on the remote machine *and* you make it so that the passwords are identical, you can grant that user access to resources on the server and it will work. It's not a great solution since you need to know that user's password and you need to keep it in sync.

If you need this kind of control, you really need AD.

Comment: Thanks :) I forgot to mention that it's a "server core" install, so I need the remote access for basic administration. I only have one server and two users so AD might be overkill.

Comment: How are you finding server core?  Now I've seen MS' "Metro" interface, I'm thinking core may be the way to go in the future...